# Submodule error repository not found for primary source and source version

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I'm doing something straightforward to clone a repo and submodules, I get this error just trying to clone my public repository:

```
[Container] 2021/10/16 06:30:02 Waiting for agent ping
[Container] 2021/10/16 06:30:03 Waiting for DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
Submodule error repository not found for primary source and source version main
```

The build spec is just a simple thing at the moment:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - ./install-packages
  build:
    commands:
      - echo '...replace with real build commands...'

artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
```

The repo is here: https://github.com/queglay/firehawk

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: We need more info - share your `buildspec` contents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out there was an ideal solution to this...

Disable "Use Git submodules" in "Edit Source" for the project.

Then in the build spec we could use native git commands to clone submodules the way git wants to:

```
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - git submodule init
      - git submodule update --recursive
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue myself. I suspect that the problem was our AWS account was using an outdated (former team-member's) github login to link the project. The fix ended up being:

1. Edit Source for the CodeBuild project
2. Under "Connection Status", try Disconnecting from Github
3. Re-connect your login in the OAuth window prompt
4. Re-try the build

Comment: Thank you for suggesting this - it saved me hours of pain. Appreciate you kind internet sir!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this from AWS support was not what I was hoping - the git sub-modules in the super project use relative refs and AWS code build does not support this at this time.